# How to remove android menu bar?

Tags: android, menubar

Here I add the screen shot of my application, I want to hide this menu bar which is below to the screen. how can  I do this ? plz help

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to specifiy targetSDKVersion in Manifest higher or equal than Android 3.0 than this button disappears (instead the OptionsMenu Entries - if any - are shown in Actionbar):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

If you want to hide the complete Navigation bar (including "Back", "Home" etc) you can do this with this Code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

But as soon as the user taps the screen it will be visible again.